# Wrong mouseenter event on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, jquery-events

I have an input inside div element. The input is hidden by default and should be visible when mouse will be over container. Upon any `keydown` event the input should be hidden. Obviously user have to click on input field to entry text.

Here is my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T6PexciPomWXsius9H2g?p=preview)

```
 var container = $('#container');
 var flicker = $('#flicker').hide();
  var log = $('#log');
  container.on('mouseenter', function() {
    flicker.show();
    log.prepend('<div>mouseenter</div>');
  });
  flicker.on('keydown', function() {
    flicker.hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      flicker.show();
    }, 4000);
  })
```

It works perfectly on Chrome, but fails on Firefox (OS x).
On Firefox the input field doesn't disappeared, and works undesirable.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The input won't receive any key events if it doesn't have focus.

Comment: @nnnnnn obviously user have to click on input field

Comment: @nnnnnn did you see the plnkr?

Comment: Nope. I can't access that site from here. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to directly include a [runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Sorry makes no sense. Why using the `flicker.on('keydown', function() {` at all!!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just imagine escape or tab keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a firefox bug.

I figured out the way.
It's quite simple. 
Just use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`. Say use `flicker.addClass('hidden')` instead of `flicker.hide()` or something like this.

The another approach is to off mouseenter event after `flicker.hide()` and enable again after 150ms. But it looks a bit ugly because of setTimeout.

[The css example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/rlNYkjFoxvBVmZo88bHK?p=preview)

The css approach works nicely in firefox, chrome, safari, opera.
But be aware of the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone) between `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`.